# How to set value to combobox on button click event in extjs

Tags: extjs

I m trying to create multiple combo boxes on button click event and  I wanted to set different values to it. And all of these combos have same store.
But i cant set values to these combos.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set combobox value in its configuration by `value` config option.

```
var count = 0;

var btn = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    handler: function() {
        count++;

        var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            displayField: 'name',
            value: count,
            valueField: 'id'
        });

        container.add(combo);
    }
});
```

**Check this fiddle: [Fiddle with live example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/elu)**